# Sorting with np.sort but the result is not right

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, numpy

This is what i have

```
import numpy as np    
import scipy.special as sp

ni = input("Digite o valor N Inicial: ") #Ask for a initial N    
ne = input ("Digite o valor N Final: ") #Ask for Final N

vet= np.arange(ni,ne+1) #Arrange A Vector with the Ns given

x = np.linspace (-1, 1, 100)

def polinomios (vet, x):
    vetr = [0]*(ne-ni+1)
    for j in range (ne-ni+1):
        for p in range (ne-ni+1):
            vetr[p] = sp.legendre(vet[j])(x)

    return (vetr)

P = polinomios (vet, x)    
print P
```

And i get like this

```
[array([ 1.        , -0.24609375,  1.        ]), array([ 1.        , -0.24609375,  1.        ]), array([ 1.        , -0.24609375,  1.        ]), array([ 1.        , -0.24609375,  1.        ]), array([ 1.        , -0.24609375,  1.        ]), array([ 1.        , -0.24609375,  1.        ]), array([ 1.        , -0.24609375,  1.        ]), array([ 1.        , -0.24609375,  1.        ]), array([ 1.        , -0.24609375,  1.        ])]
```

And I cant find a way to get it looks like this, but without putting the smaller number on the first collunn:

```
[[-0.24609375  1.          1.        ]
 [-0.24609375  1.          1.        ]
 [-0.24609375  1.          1.        ]
 [-0.24609375  1.          1.        ]
 [-0.24609375  1.          1.        ]
 [-0.24609375  1.          1.        ]
 [-0.24609375  1.          1.        ]
 [-0.24609375  1.          1.        ]
 [-0.24609375  1.          1.        ]]
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried to fix whatever your problem might be?

Comment: What do you mean by `np.sort` "rearranged the number"? Can you show an example of what it gives you so we can see how it differs from what you expect? Also, it may help if you could provide a more minimal code example - especially, one that doesn't rely on us guessing the right user input to get the output you're showing.

Comment: an example, the answer that i got was [1,-2,-4,5,6,][1,5,2,3,-5] and np.sort did:

[-4,-2, 1, 2, 5, 6]

[-5, 1, 2, 3, 5]

 i want to look like the "hand made matrix" but without making the numbers from smaller to bigger.

Comment: Can you reduce your problem to a smaller example and provide your expected output.

Comment: Ok sorry @Akavall, just edited the question to a smaller example

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do. Is your question just about `np.sort()`? I don't understand your expected output. It is usually best to provide a smallest possible example that gets the point of what you are doing across (Yours is still to big), and provide concrete sample output that you expect.

Comment: Your example has `o`, `0`, and `pi` in it but your output doesn't have any of those values. Are those just made up? Can you make an example of your desired output based on your current output?

Comment: Do you just want to make it into one array?  Try just `np.array(P)`

Comment: ok I sorry for the confuse question, edited again. @Akavall

Comment: Edited to try to make easier to understand @askewchan

Comment: Did you try my suggestion to use `np.array(P)`?

Comment: Wow sorry, I didnt saw that you commented twice in a row @askewchan
I tried it before, and it didnt work, but know it worked fine, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I did like @askewchan said and used np.array(P) and it worked.

```
[[ 1.         -0.5         1.        ]
 [-1.          0.          1.        ]
 [ 1.          0.375       1.        ]
 [-1.          0.          1.        ]
 [ 1.         -0.3125      1.        ]
 [-1.          0.          1.        ]
 [ 1.          0.2734375   1.        ]
 [-1.          0.          1.        ]
 [ 1.         -0.24609375  1.        ]]
```